# Would using mouse position in the below scenario generate true random numbers?

Tags: randomness, random-number-generator

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around random number generation so I figure it would be better to ask now, rather than screw up later.

Let's say I want to write a function that generates a random lucky number from 0-9 when the user clicks on a button.

I'm thinking of using the last digit of the multiple of the x and y coordinates of the click position as the output.

Assuming that the user have no intention of gaming the output, would this be true randomness because there's no way for a 3rd party to predict where on the button the user will click next?

Comment: Don't do it. Use a random number generator supplied by the system.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, mouse click position is highly correlated. Just as an example, take a look to a [typical mouse interaction with a browser](http://jeffhuang.com/Final_CursorBehavior_CHI11.pdf):

[image: Heatmap of mouse click positions]

So, the use of raw mouse click positions without pre-whitening is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Using the system clock is better than mouse position.  Use the exact
time (as high precision as is available) as the seed for a random number
generator, not the system time itself.  Something like

```
int lucky = new Random(System.currentTime()).nextInt(10);
```